# actions on touchesMoved in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to start developing cocos2d games. So, I'm new in cocos2d, but I developed few applications on iPhone. I installed cocos templates (v2.0) and created new project with box2d phisics. Here I can see a demo project with blocks and some menus. When I tap screen, new block appears, and falls to the botton of screen. Than must be implemented here:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Add a new body/atlas sprite at the touched location
    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

        [self addNewSpriteAtPosition: location];
    }
}
```

so, sprite appears when touches ended. **But how to do something when touches begun or moved?** I cant this finds methods for cocos. I saw some tutorials,  there is method like this:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   return YES;
}
```

but it never called... What am I doung wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement

```
(BOOL)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

And ensure you have

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;.
```

in your `init` method for that layer.

Comment: If you want to use ccTouchBegan instead of ccTouches you need to add the targeted delegate. See here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8354

Answer (score 0):

Implement:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       // whatever is needed here
       return YES;
}
```

in your cocos2d class (the same implementing `ccTouchesEnded`), then it will be called.

Comment: thx for responce, but as was I say, I tyed it. I put this code with `NSLog (@"qwd3");` but no log messages was posted on touch... thats why I asking...